# Disable ActiveX Control from consuming mouse motion or button clicks in MATLAB GUI?

Tags: matlab, interface, camera, activex

I'm making a MATLAB GUI to control a set of cameras (Thorlabs DCC1545M) which offer an ActiveX interface. One of the functions I'd like to achieve is to be able to click on the camera display window and obtain the currentPoint data (with respect to the window).

I can easily achieve this with a generic figure, but once an ActiveX control is loaded, mouse events which occur over the ActiveX region are consumed by the ActiveX control, and do not call the figure's event functions. Mouse events which occur outside this region respond as expected.

Any suggestions on how to disable the ActiveX's priority over the mouse events? Or other workarounds?

Cheers,

Comment: The best example I can give is example #27 from the GUI example pack by Matt Fig (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples)

Now imagine that, but instead of an axes component, one were to use an ActiveX component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working Matlab file that should do what you're looking for:

```
exl = actxserver('excel.application');
exlWkbk = exl.Workbooks;
exlFile = exlWkbk.Open(['C:\mypath\ExcelCOM.xls']);
 exlSheet1 = exlFile.Sheets.Item('Sheet1');
 robj = exlSheet1.Columns.End(4);       % Find the end of the column
 numrows = robj.row;                    % And determine what row it is
 dat_range = ['D2:G' num2str(numrows)]; % Read to the last row
 rngObj = exlSheet1.Range(dat_range);
 exlData = rngObj.Value;
 for ii = 1:size(exlData,2)
    matData(:,ii) = reshape([exlData{2:end,ii}],size(exlData(2:end,ii)));
    lBoxList{ii} = [exlData{1,ii}];
 end
 exl.visible = true;
 for j=1:size(exlData,2)
     for k=1:13
         A(k+2,j)=0
         A(k,j)=matData(k,j)
     end
 end
 exlWkbk.Close
 exl.Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

So my current workaround will be to do a getImage of the current camera frame, turn off visibility to the ActiveX component, and replace it with the image.

"windowbuttonmotionfcn" works over images in MATLAB, and all I really lose out on is a continuous live feed from the camera.